# Минимизация json во время сборки jar в gradle

Tags: json, gradle

В ${project}/src/main/resources лежат файлы разных форматов.
Мне нужно во время выполнения моего таска минимизировать(удалить все двойные пробелы и переносы строк) все *.json из ${project}/src/main/resources и всех его подпапок.
(Потом хочу проделать такие же действия и с *.css, *.xml итп)
Как это сделать используя gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Copy task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) позволяет использовать фильтры:

```
task minimize(type: Copy) {
    from('src/main/resources') {
        include '**/*.json'
        include '**/*.xml'
        include '**/*.css'
        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.StripLineBreaks)
        filter(StripDoubleSpaces)
    }
    into 'target'
}
```

Чтобы убрать переводы строк можно использовать стандартный ant фильтр StripLineBreaks. А вот для удаления двойных пробелов, видимо, придется написать свой фильтр, потому что фильтр для замены регулярных выражений в ant реализован как 'плагин' к TokenFilter, который надо добавлять в цепочку фильтров вызовом TokenFilter.add(), а метод filter() принимает на вход не объект, а тип, то есть TokenFilter сконфигурировать не удастся.

```
public class StripLineBreaks extends org.apache.tools.ant.filters.TokenFilter {
    public StripLineBreaks() {
        ReplaceRegex regexFilter = new ReplaceRegex();
        regexFilter.setPattern( "\\s+" );
        regexFilter.setReplace( " " );
        add( regexFilter );
    }
}
```